# How to make my firestore listeners secure/security?

Tags: node.js, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, listener

Hello I have a listener with firebase so that whenever there is a change that it will do a function. I need to put this listener in a software so that when it detects a change that it will perform a function. How would I be able to put this listener in my other code and make sure that my database stays secure and that nobody will be able to mess with it?

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const app = express();


const db = admin.firestore()


exports.onCreate = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const values = snap.data();

    
    await db.collection('logging').add({description : `SKU was sent to discord with ${values.username}`})
})
```

Comment: "my database stays secure and that nobody will be able to mess with it" You'll have to clarify what you mean by that. If you want to learn how to control access to your database with Firebase's server-side security rules, have a look here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules

Answer (score 0):

Using Firebase functions and Firestore, you can do the following:

Keep all your Firebase functions server-side, no client-side anything. Server-side functions have admin access but they stay inaccessible to anyone except the firebase account owners/managers.

You then use an "[onUpdate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#function_triggers)" firebase function: every time your document (data) changes, your Firebase function runs.

So what should it do?

Simply have it call your external (untrustworthy) software via an HTTP GET or POST call. You can do that using [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), and even pass JSON or query parameters to that external software. You can have that external code do what it's supposed to do, without ever having to interact directly with your database.